# Shapely library to EXE

Tags: python-3.x

Shapely library.
With PY it works, but when we make an EXE via https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/ it doesn't want to work.
So how to handle it?

[image: Text]

Comment: I don’t have access to my computer right now so I can’t test anything, but it seems that shapely is connected to [GEOS](https://github.com/libgeos/geos), which looks to be a C++ geometry library. It’s possible that pyinstaller can’t locate the shared library, and so you would have to add it yourself, maybe using the —add-data option. I hope this helps but let me know if you can’t make it work and I’ll look into it further.